# Genexus Synchronize Documentation con Wiki6

Tags: genexus

Bajé del open de GxServer la kb Wiki6, y esta ejecutándose sin problemas en java + tomcat.
Por otro lado tengo otra kb desarrollada por mi la cual quiero que la documentación sea enviada a esa wiki.

Lo que no estoy logrando es conectar el IDE de Gx a la wiki.
Estoy haciendo todo como dice en
[la documentación oficial de Gx](https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?5259,Category%3ASynchronize%20Documentation)

pero al momento de dar botón derecho > syncronize with external wiki el botón de Syncronize me aparece inhabilitado y el status es no conectado.

Agradezco si alguien puede ayudarme a ver que estoy haciendo mal.
(Gx16 + Java + Tomcat)

Saludos.